# nginx caching work wrong, nginx cache auth system, logout not work (on DJANGO), how to fix?

Tags: nginx, cache, django

nginx is caching everything, if I login to the system, then I can no longer exit it until the caching expires, since I'm Logout from the account, i need to know how to delete cookies and session!

> by default, Django itself removes cookies and sessions when exiting,
>   using the standard method to exit the account from the developers
>   django, I use it, if you disable caching at nginx, then everything
>   works fine!

nginx conf "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"

```
##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

proxy_connect_timeout 5;
proxy_send_timeout 10;
proxy_read_timeout 10;

proxy_buffering on;
proxy_buffer_size 16k;
proxy_buffers 24 16k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

proxy_temp_path /tmp/nginx/proxy_temp;
add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
    proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:100m;
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx/cache2 levels=1:2 keys_zone=two:100m;
proxy_cache one;
proxy_cache_valid any 30d;
proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$request_uri$cookie_US;
```

my server conf

```
upstream theband {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # ssingle worker for timing out).

  server unix:/webapps/theband/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen   80;
    server_name 207.154.232.99;
    expires 35d;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /webapps/theband/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /webapps/theband/logs/nginx-error.log;
    error_log /webapps/theband/logs/nginx-crit-error.log crit;
    error_log /webapps/theband/logs/nginx-debug.log debug; 
    location /static/ {
        alias   /webapps/theband/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /webapps/theband/media/;
    }
    location ~* ^(?!/media).*.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
        alias /tmp/nginx/trash/trash_media;
        expires 35d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        access_log off;
    }    
    location ~* ^(?!/static).*.(?:css|js|html)$ {
    root /tmp/nginx/trash/trash_static;
        expires 35d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        access_log off;
    }     

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_cache one;
        proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

        # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
        #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # enable this if and only if you use HTTPS, this helps Rack
        # set the proper protocol for doing redirects:
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
        # can be set properly within the Rack application
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
        # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
        proxy_redirect off;

        # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
        # Comet/long-poll stuff.  It's also safe to set if you're
        # using only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx.
        # Otherwise you _want_ nginx to buffer responses to slow
        # clients, really.
        #proxy_buffering off;

        # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
        # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://theband;
            break;
        }
    }
    error_page 404 /error_404.html;
    location = /error_404.html {
        root /webapps/theband/src/templates;
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page  500 502 503 504 /error_500.html;
    location = /error_500.html {
        root /webapps/theband/src/templates;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `alias` where you have used `root` in some of your locations. That's not related to your login issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm crying, I've spent a lot of time solving this problem, although I knew what the problem was, and how to solve it roughly, but I just add SIMPLE, SIMPLY 1 line of code .... CARL We had to put this `proxy_pass http://theband;`

kill me pls(...

well make like this and cache for specific url is gonna be disabled and acceses to page be work!

```
location /accounts/logout {
    proxy_no_cache 1;
    proxy_cache_bypass 1;
    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    if_modified_since off;
    expires -1;
    proxy_pass http://theband;
    etag off;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In nginx you could set a location for your admin pages that explicitly doesn't cache, so try something like:

```
location /admin {
    expires -1;
    Cache-control no-cache;
}
```

should do it. There are also header control extensions for django that can do the same thing. Cloudflare should honour these headers without any changes.

Comment: location /admin/* {
        proxy_no_cache 1;
        proxy_cache_bypass 1;
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
        add_header Cache-Control 'private no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;

    }

Comment: so it's mean that i can logout, because of this cloud flare?

Comment: still nothing, and when i login into admin, then i can logout any more!

Comment: now, cloud flare block connection to admin page, give 404, problem into nginx caching probably!

Comment: If you're using the stock django admin it also has its own caching for which there are extensions that manage it, such as this one: https://github.com/PaesslerAG/django-admin-caching.
Also consider switching off caching altogether in Cloudflare and nginx, and make sure you can access the admin interface directly from gunicorn serving HTTP.
The other option is to serve the admin interface as a subdomain with server side caching disabled.

Comment: i create special page rules, do not allow caching averything, but still the same, after first login, a cannot logout, i just stay login, if i delete browser cahcing, so i can relogin, but gonna be the same!i use ordinary admin page on django, problem probably into nginx caching, if set "location /admin" then cloud falre block acces through browser to admin page, and still i can logout, problem into nginx, help pls)))

Comment: You're going to have to work through it sequentially. 
- How does it work with the development server?

Comment: I'm developing on the local host, on windows, then I'm running through the git, and everything on the local one works great, as I understood, when you click on the exit from the account, the cache is not deleted, and nothing goes to the server, cloud flare in the right pages, it is registered that did not cache only admin, more about a cache anything is not present.

Comment: now my server on ubuntu  the newest ver, nginx

Comment: https://therockband.tk/

Comment: You need to disable cache-control for /admin in Cloudflare as it's returning max-age=3024000. However, concentrate on testing directly to nginx and use developer tools to work out what is being returned from there. If you need the hostname, set it in your hostfile on your local machine.

Comment: I wrote that I disabled the caching of the admin panel, and all that is associated with it in the cloud flare in the page rules

Comment: Have you tested going directly to nginx? You are going to have to take Cloudflare out of the path altogether to test as it caches very aggressively by default.

Comment: I've given you a lot of things to look at, have you tried them?

Comment: yes man, seems like i said you, problem in nginx caching, i delete cloudflare, disable all there, disable http, ssl, everything, and still the same, if i login, i can not log out!

Comment: log out work once, i mean, if login into first time, and then logout, all okey, but the next time, i can not logout!

Comment: i'll disable cahing on nginx level, log out works great, lgoin everything!i suppose, i need how do I do a delete session and cookies, help pls

Comment: Session and cookie management is managed by django. I can remember fixing this issue with a site probably seven or eight years ago but I can't remember the details and it's probably changed since then. At a guess you have to expire the cookie on logout, but there are more qualified people elsewhere who can help with that.

Comment: Well Well, we came back from where we started, where I said my problem from, in any case, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

On logout you need to set some different headers, so that nginx knows to expire the proxy cache. The proxy_module stuff is what is causing the "problem"

`Buffering can also be enabled or disabled by passing “yes” or “no” in the “X-Accel-Buffering” response header field. This capability can be disabled using the proxy_ignore_headers directive.`

[nginx proxy module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html)

If you are also using Cloudflare you should also be sending expires and cache control headers. You can do this in Django with [patch_response_headers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.cache.patch_response_headers). Cloudflare will respect these. If you are using full page caching you can add another PageRule to never cache the admin stuff. Full page caching is only enabled through PageRules.

Comment: I watched this module, but there are only scraps of code, without explaining how to put them, and specifically what are they for! I will be glad if you help such a beginner like me, thank.